# 50 amp GFCI Tripping randomly

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, gfci, load, circuit

My 50 amp GFCI Breaker tripped periodically so I disconnected the load wires from the lugs and turned it back on And after about a minute it tripped again. I then changed the breaker and it tripped again. It is a new 200amp service. Is the main 200 amp breaker bad or could it be a load imbalance from the power source, there is a commercial water well across the road.

Comment: Do you know if it is the GFCI tripping or the actual fuse tripping? They are reset differently.

Also, do you have other GFCI outlets installed in the same circuit as the main GFCI fuse? If you do, that is incorrectly done and GFCI will trip each other if they are on the same circuit.

Comment: What make and model is said GFCI breaker?